# Looking for a PHP Instant Messaging Solution

Tags: php

Anybody know of any Instant messaging solution that can be deployed on LAMP?
Did some Google search and most of the solution i got were not working as advertised :(
Would appreciate a pointer to any tried and tested solution!

Merci!

Comment: Nice of you to include the ones you've already tried...

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you know the Instant Messenger called "jabber"? They use an open protocoll. There are PHP-Classes existing, which can communicate via jabber. So you could write messages from PHP 2 your Jabber-Client. But I don't know, if this is what you are searching for. If so, look at google, for "jabber php class" or something like that...

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://www.intramessenger.net/